# How to write a 32 Bit D-Word to Windows registry in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, dword

I am trying to disable the Windows Defender using a C++ Win32API application.
To do that I need to write a D Word into the registry (DisableAntiSpyware = 1).
I always do that manually after installing a new Windows.
So here is my code, but its not working.
Maybe someone could tell me why or what is wrong with it. Thank you!

OK I've changed the code a bit, still not working...

```
        case 1:

            //::MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
            ::MessageBox(hWnd, L"Button was Pressed",L"Button was clicked?",MB_OK);

            LONG
            SetRegValue
            (
            const wchar_t* path
            , const wchar_t *name
            , const BYTE *value

                );
            {
                LONG status;
                HKEY hKey;

                DWORD value = 0x00000001;

                status = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"\\SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
                if ((status == ERROR_SUCCESS) && (hKey != NULL))
                {
                    status = RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"test", 0, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&value,sizeof(value));
                    RegCloseKey(hKey);
                }
                return status;

                ::MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
            }
        }
    }
    break;
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical description of a problem. What exactly happens when you run this? What are the return codes on each line?

Comment: how you call `RegSetValueEx` completely wrong. must be `DWORD d = 1;RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"test", REG_DWORD, &d, sizeof(d));`

Comment: You are probably just ignoring the [Registry Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx) and then it gets all mad, and ignores you.

Comment: At first the Message Box comes up and says that the Button was clicked, but it doesn't write into registry.
How can I check for return codes?
I will try to find out :)

Comment: I get this message.

argument of type unsigned int is incompatible with parameter of type const BYTE *

Comment: And too few arguments in function call.

Comment: If you're setting a `REG_DWORD` you have to give it a `DWORD`, not a string.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening a Registry key, you should request only the rights you actually need.  So replace `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` with `KEY_SET_VALUE` instead, since all you are doing is writing a value.  But even then, you might still need to run your app with elevated permissions in order to write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MAHCINE`, unless you give your user account write access to the Windows Defender key beforehand.

Also, if your code is compiled as 32bit and runs on a 64bit system, and it needs to write to the 64bit Registry, then you have to include the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag otherwise you may be subject to [Registry Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384235.aspx)/[Registry Redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx).

Try something more like this instead:

```
case 1:
{
    ::MessageBox(hWnd, L"Button was Pressed", L"Button was clicked?", MB_OK);

    DWORD value = 1;
    DWORD flags = KEY_SET_VALUE;

    #if !defined(_WIN64)
    BOOL bIsWow64Process = FALSE;
    if (IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &bIsWow64Process) && bIsWow64Process)
        flags |= KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
    #endif

    HKEY hKey;
    LONG status = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"\\SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender", 0, flags, &hKey);
    if ((status == ERROR_SUCCESS) && (hKey != NULL))
    {
        status = RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"DisableAntiSpyware", 0, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&value, sizeof(value));
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }

    ::MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
}
break;
```

Comment: I try'd to run in administrator mode by starting Visual Studio in Administrator mode. Still not working.

Comment: And yes, I am writing 32bit code on 64bit machine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to any key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` unless the program is running with elevated privileges, i.e. administrator mode. The call to `RegOpenKeyEx` or `RegSetValueEx` will fail.

Comment: OK, I was thinking about this, but I was not sure. Thank you!
I will try to run in administrator mode.